# Cannot install Cython on win7

Tags: python, cython

So I'm trying to use Cython on ta-lib, and I'm using the wrapper provided by mrjbq7 (many thanks..). So I tried to install Cython-0.19.1 on my computer and then do `python setup.py install` on ta-lib-master (the wrapper), and I got the following:

```
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    running biuld_ext
    failed to import Cython: No module named 'Actions'
    error: Cython does not appear to be installed
```

I tried to build Cython with `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`

Can anyone please help me? Thanks a lot!

---

I'm using 32-bit Windows7 and python 3.3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think your troubles have anything to do with the fact that you're installing the `TA-lib wrapper`, so here are a few suggestions :

- First, retry to install Cython using `Python 2.7.X` (I suspect some incompatibilities between some Python versions and Cython versions : at least, the kind of errors you mentioned remind me something...).

If this doesn't help, **rebuild Cython** as follows :

1. Install MinGW (with options gcc/g++) from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/mingw-get-inst/mingw-get-inst-20120426/mingw-get-inst-20120426.exe/download).
2. Tell `disutils` to use gcc... Create file `C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\distutils.cfg` and write this inside :

   ```
   [build]
   compiler = mingw32
   ```
3. If needed, remove all instances of `-mno-cygwin` gcc option from file `C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py` :

   ```
   # self.set_executables(compiler='gcc -mno-cygwin -O -Wall',
                        # compiler_so='gcc -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall',
                        # compiler_cxx='g++ -mno-cygwin -O -Wall',
                        # linker_exe='gcc -mno-cygwin',
                        # linker_so='%s -mno-cygwin %s %s'
                                   # % (self.linker_dll, shared_option,
                                      # entry_point))
   # becomes :

   self.set_executables(compiler='gcc -O -Wall',
                        compiler_so='gcc -mdll -O -Wall',
                        compiler_cxx='g++ -O -Wall',
                        linker_exe='gcc',
                        linker_so='%s %s %s'
                                   % (self.linker_dll, shared_option,
                                      entry_point))

   # Just because `-mno-cygwin` has just been removed from early versions of gcc.
   ```
4. Build and install Cython : `$ python setup.py install`

**In any cases :** Make sure to have the proper `PATH`s for Cython :

```
SET PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;../../../DEPENDENCIES/Cython-0.19.1
SET PATH=%PATH%;../../../DEPENDENCIES/Cython-0.19.1/bin
```

Try rebuilt TA-lib and please tell me what it says ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried rebuild Cython with NMake and it worked. But when I'm building ta-lib-master it gives me this error:  `NameEooro: name 'unicode' is not defined`  This is the full message:  `File "C:\Cython-0.19.1\Cython\Compiler\Scanning.py", line 10, in <module>
   cython.declare(EncodedString=object, string_prefixes=object, raw_prefixes=object, IDENT=unicode,  NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined'`                          ___________________________________   And sorry I can't vote up your answer yet, I need 4 more rep to do this -_-"